# DataBinding for ActionBar

Tags: android, data-binding, android-actionbar

PROBLEM: Data should be bound to Views of default Android Action Bar (App Bar).

RESEARCH: [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) is based on layout.xml and its `<layout>`, `<data>` and `<variable>` tags. But I have no Android Action Bar `layout.xml`. I get its instance using `(FrameLayout) myActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();`.

QUESTION: **How can I get Android Action Bar layout to configure Data Binding in it** (as xml or programmatically)?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible.

Comment: It's a good question. I suspect in the first instance, you'd have to create a custom toolbar. But as far as whether it's possible, I can't find anything on Google yet.